# Filter with 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets-formula

i have a google sheet with a query that takes into account the filter if the values in column G are in column B.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GdL5psaLKDix7282AZXGvZJUlm7rfhU2x5KlKTjp6ig/edit?usp=sharing

But i need to add another filter to the query, taking into account the number of the user.
In other words the condition should be:

- If the countries in column G are in column B for user 1.

How can i change my initial query.

```
=query({A2:E}; "select * where Col2 = '"&JOIN("'or Col2 = '"; FILTER(G2:G;G2:G<>""))&"'")
```

Please help !

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:E}; 
 "where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; FILTER(G2:G; H2:H=1))&"'"; 0)
```

[image]